# Why I can't declare a private variable in a class in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

the codes below gives me a error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in Line 4

```
 <?php
  class mydb
  {     
    $mydblink = mysqli_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc','test' );         
     public static function checklink() {
        if ( !$mydblink ) {
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
        }
        echo 'Connection OK';
        mysql_close($mydblink);
    }

                  }
  mydb::checklink();
```

but move $mydblink into the function makes it work,

```
  <?php
  class mydb
  {     
    public static function checklink() {
        $mydblink = mysqli_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc','test' );         

        if ( !$mydblink ) {
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
        }
        echo 'Connection OK';
        mysql_close($mydblink);
    }

  }
  mydb::checklink();
```

why? Does it mean that I can't declare a private variable in a class in PHP?

Comment: Why aren't you using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)? The `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a private variable, but you can not execute code like  mysql_connect in your class property declaration. You can only set primitives.

```
class MyDB {
  private $dbc;
  private $someInteger = 4; // you can do this
  private $someArray = array(); // and this.

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->dbc = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
  }

  public function getDbc()
  {
    return $this->dbc;
  }

}

$system = new MyDB();
//$system->getDbc()->soSomethingWithMyDb();
```

Also, please note that mysql_ is deprecated. I would advise you to use mysqli_ or PDO

Answer (score 2):

Code in classes needs to be inside a function:

```
class mydb{     
    // Parse error
    $mydblink = mysql_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc','test' );  
}
```

```
class mydb{     
    // Correct
    public function __construct(){
        $this->mydblink = mysql_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc','test' );  
    }
}
```

Comment: the first sentence explains all :P really helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it as a variable, for example;

```
private $mydblink = mysql_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc','test' );
```

Edit: this might be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: In the function, also, you would need to reference `$mydblink` as `$this->mydblink`

Answer (score 0):

As a side note `mysql_connect` requires 3 parameter you passed 4 here

```
mysql_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc','test' );
```

should be

```
mysql_connect( 'localhost:3306','root','123qweasdzxc');
mysql_select_db('test');
```

Comment: I follow the grammar here, said it has 4 parameters:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: @AlbertGao Read carefully here, it says `mysqli` not `mysql`. `mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);`

Comment: [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php) 5 parameters...  @AlbertGao have a look at http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thanks for mention me that :P